# R: cummean() over subset

Tags: r

I'm new to R and also stackoverflow, so pls bear with me if I'm doing something wrong here...

So I'm working on soccer data, which looks like this:

```
  Div     Date      HomeTeam   AwayTeam FTHG FTAG avgHG_league avgHG_team
1  D1 14/08/15 Bayern Munich    Hamburg    5    0           NA          0
2  D1 15/08/15      Augsburg     Hertha    0    1     5.000000          0
3  D1 15/08/15     Darmstadt   Hannover    2    2     2.500000          0
4  D1 15/08/15      Dortmund M'gladbach    4    0     2.333333          0
5  D1 15/08/15    Leverkusen Hoffenheim    2    1     2.750000          0
6  D1 15/08/15         Mainz Ingolstadt    0    1     2.600000          0
```

I've created the avgHG_league column to give me the average goals that teams at home scored so far in the season, with the following code:

```
BLfiltered <- BLfiltered %>%
  mutate(avgHG_league = lag(cummean(FTHG),1))
```

Now in the avgHG_team column I want to do pretty much the same, but instead of calculating the mean of goals of all home teams together, I only want to calculate the mean of goals that only **this particular hometeam** has scored at home **so far** in the season (but not including this game)...

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

/E: column "FTHG" gives us the home goals from each match

Comment: Which column tells us about the Home Team score at home?

Comment: If you use `tidyr::gather` on `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` so you've got one `team` column (and one home/away one), you can `group_by` team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution.  It uses the dplyr package which I assume you are already using since you are calling `cummean` in  your example. For simplicity I have called the data `sd` for soccer data.

```
sd = mutate(sd,avgHG_league=lag(cummean(FTHG),1,0)) %.% group_by(HomeTeam) %.% mutate(avgHG_Team=lag(cummean(FTHG),1,0)) %.% ungroup()
```

Note: Adding the `0` in the lag statments (technically `default=0`) places `0` instead of `NA` for your initial values which I believe is what you want.

Results from the following dummy data

### Data

```
    Div     Date      HomeTeam   AwayTeam FTHG FTAG
1   D1 14/08/15 Bayern Munich    Hamburg    5    0
2   D1 15/08/15      Augsburg     Hertha    0    1
3   D1 15/08/15     Darmstadt   Hannover    2    2
4   D1 15/08/15      Dortmund M'gladbach    4    0
5   D1 15/08/15    Leverkusen Hoffenheim    2    1
6   D1 15/08/15         Mainz Ingolstadt    0    1
7   D1 15/09/15 Bayern Munich    Hamburg    0    0
8   D1 15/10/15      Augsburg     Hertha    0    0
9   D1 15/10/15     Darmstadt   Hannover    0    0
10  D1 15/10/15      Dortmund M'gladbach    0    0
11  D1 15/10/15    Leverkusen Hoffenheim    0    0
12  D1 15/10/15         Mainz Ingolstadt    0    0
13  D1 15/11/15 Bayern Munich    Hamburg    0    0
14  D1 15/10/16      Augsburg     Hertha    0    0
15  D1 15/11/16     Darmstadt   Hannover    0    0
16  D1 15/10/17      Dortmund M'gladbach    0    0
17  D1 15/11/17    Leverkusen Hoffenheim    0    0
18  D1 15/10/18         Mainz Ingolstadt    0    0
```

### Results

```
    Div   Date        HomeTeam   AwayTeam FTHG FTAG avgHG_league avgHG_Team
1   D1 14/08/15 Bayern Munich    Hamburg    5    0    0.0000000        0.0
2   D1 15/08/15      Augsburg     Hertha    0    1    5.0000000        0.0
3   D1 15/08/15     Darmstadt   Hannover    2    2    2.5000000        0.0
4   D1 15/08/15      Dortmund M'gladbach    4    0    2.3333333        0.0
5   D1 15/08/15    Leverkusen Hoffenheim    2    1    2.7500000        0.0
6   D1 15/08/15         Mainz Ingolstadt    0    1    2.6000000        0.0
7   D1 15/09/15 Bayern Munich    Hamburg    0    0    2.1666667        5.0
8   D1 15/10/15      Augsburg     Hertha    0    0    1.8571429        0.0
9   D1 15/10/15     Darmstadt   Hannover    0    0    1.6250000        2.0
10  D1 15/10/15      Dortmund M'gladbach    0    0    1.4444444        4.0
11  D1 15/10/15    Leverkusen Hoffenheim    0    0    1.3000000        2.0
12  D1 15/10/15         Mainz Ingolstadt    0    0    1.1818182        0.0
13  D1 15/11/15 Bayern Munich    Hamburg    0    0    1.0833333        2.5
14  D1 15/10/16      Augsburg     Hertha    0    0    1.0000000        0.0
15  D1 15/11/16     Darmstadt   Hannover    0    0    0.9285714        1.0
16  D1 15/10/17      Dortmund M'gladbach    0    0    0.8666667        2.0
17  D1 15/11/17    Leverkusen Hoffenheim    0    0    0.8125000        1.0
18  D1 15/10/18         Mainz Ingolstadt    0    0    0.7647059        0.0
```

### Sources

A similar data processing approach can be seen here: https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/

This is also a great resource for data manipulation in R using tidyr and dplyr: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention this approach assumes the data begins sorted by date as in your example data set.

Comment: Edit: added `ungroup` to return data frame to original state as inspired by @EricCachon

Comment: Yes @Cole, it is good idea to add `ungroup` if you did not use `summarise` after `by_group`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it in base `R` provided the input data are sorted by `HomeTeam` and then `Date`:

```
my.data <- read.csv(text = '
  Div,     Date,      HomeTeam,   AwayTeam, FTHG, FTAG
   D1, 14/08/15, Bayern Munich,    Hamburg,    5,    0
   D1, 15/08/15, Bayern Munich,     Hertha,    0,    1
   D1, 16/08/15,     Darmstadt,   Hannover,    2,    2
   D1, 17/08/15,     Darmstadt, Ingolstadt,    4,    0
   D1, 18/08/15,     Darmstadt, Hoffenheim,    2,    1
   D1, 19/08/15,         Mainz, Ingolstadt,    0,    1
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)

my.data <- my.data[with(my.data, order(HomeTeam, Date)), ]
my.data

my.means <- aggregate(my.data$FTHG, by=list(my.data$HomeTeam), 
            FUN = {function(x) cumsum(x)/seq(from=1, to=length(x)) })

my.data$my.cum.means <- c(unlist(my.means[2]))
my.data

#
#     Div     Date      HomeTeam   AwayTeam FTHG FTAG my.cum.means
#x.11  D1 14/08/15 Bayern Munich    Hamburg    5    0     5.000000
#x.12  D1 15/08/15 Bayern Munich     Hertha    0    1     2.500000
#x.21  D1 16/08/15     Darmstadt   Hannover    2    2     2.000000
#x.22  D1 17/08/15     Darmstadt Ingolstadt    4    0     3.000000
#x.23  D1 18/08/15     Darmstadt Hoffenheim    2    1     2.666667
#x.3   D1 19/08/15         Mainz Ingolstadt    0    1     0.000000
#
```